How to create register system that automatically give each user his own Bitcoin address
I am a complete newbie and I made a website that will have a register system.
I need to know how I can make a wallet that automatically generate a new address for each new register and of course handle the deposit and withdraw.
I searched a lot and did not find an answer.
how can I do that and what language besides java I need to learn?

There's java libarary for bitcoin, bitcoinj. You can check its documentation(https://bitcoinj.org/working-with-the-wallet).
